# Applying different kernels to parts of a dataset and merging the output

Tags: svm, scikit-learn, kernel-trick, rbf-kernel

I am trying to create a classifier using SVM on a dataset that is composed of 6 sets of data for each of my observations. When I train the SVM (rbf kernel), I get a better performance of the classifier when I use only 2 out of 6 sets of features (reducing the number of features to about half): when I add features, my accuracy degrades by over 5%. I understand that "junk in, junk out", but we were surprised by the magnitude of this effect. Note that I scale the features to all have the same range and variance before training the SVM (using `sklearn`'s `MinMaxScaler()`).

Our interpretation of this result is that we are not representing the feature space correctly - by calculating a single kernel on all 6 sets of features at the same time, I lose information from each single set of features. To make up for this, I want to calculate a kernel on each feature set independently (and so also find the optimal `gamma` separately) and then concatenate the results to train the classifier (a bit like what described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46442/mixed-svm-kernel-of-rbf-and-linear?rq=1)). Basically, I would like to do:

$$
k_{final} = k_1(X_1) + k_2(X_2) + k_3(X_3) + k_4(X_4) + k_5(X_5) + k_6(X_6)
$$

1. Is this something that can be done and a sensible thing to do? And would it help with my problem?
2. If so, can I implement this in `sklearn`? If so, how?

I have found a way to calculate kernels in `sklearn` (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#gp-kernels), and so I could calculate the kernel on each set separately. However, once I output the distance matrix, I am not sure how I would use it to train the SVM.

*My understanding of kernels is only very intuitive, so I would appreciate an answer with limited maths!*

Comment: The sum of kernels is also a kernel, so from that perspective it's valid. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270967/proof-of-sum-of-kernels-of-concatenated-vector // Whether or not it's a good idea for you problem is, of course problem-dependent, so I'm not sure we can answer that directly. // "How do I ___ in [python/R/Excel]" is not an on-topic question here.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica thank you for pointing me to that question! 
One more question: if I am using different kernels, do I still need to scale the features beforehand or does that become less important (assuming they are all similar within one subset)?

Comment: Generally, scaling gives better results, but this isn't always true. See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172795/scaling-for-svm-destroys-my-results